# using forEach on dataset of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, foreach

How do i use a forEach function on the dataset to get the names of the objects which have 2 or more friends? I want to display the names in which the objects have 2 or more friends so should display "John".

data.js

```
const data = [
 {
    "index": "14",
    "name": "Bob",
    "age": "23",
    "friends": [
        {
          "id": 0,
          "name": "Lancaster Howell"
        }
     ],
  },
  {
    "index": "23",
    "name": "John",
    "age": "30",
     "friends": [
        {
          "id": 0,
          "name": "Lancaster Howell"
        }
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Lancaster Howell"
        }
     ],
  },

]
```

app.js (what i am trying)

```
data.forEach((object) => {
  if (object.friends.length > 1) {
    ???
  }
});
```

Comment: You should try `.filter()` and `.map()` or `.reduce()` instead of `.forEach()`.

Comment: If you really just want to log the names, you can us `console.log(object.name)` for your `???` and you are done

Comment: I specifically need to use forEach with this scenario but think map would do the same thing, also @fynsta I can't believe I didn't see that. been a long day. Thanks yall

Comment: Why is forEach() required?

Comment: it isn't in normally, this is just part of a small a challenge i was doing to learn. There are always several ways to do it though I am sure. I could replace forEach with map and it does the same thing, not sure that it is the same thing though? I think map makes a new array is a difference but reading documentation now.

Answer (score 1):

Hey You can use in this way.

```
const data = [
 {
    "index": "14",
    "name": "Bob",
    "age": "23",
    "friends": [
        {
          "id": 0,
          "name": "Lancaster Howell"
        }
     ],
  },
  {
    "index": "23",
    "name": "John",
    "age": "30",
     "friends": [
        {
          "id": 0,
          "name": "Lancaster Howell"
        }
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Lancaster Howell"
        }
     ],
  },

]
// need to filter out on the basis of having more then 2 friend
const filtewithFriend = data.filter((item)=>(item.friends.length >= 2));
// console all having more than 2 friend
const getNameofuser = filtewithFriend.map((data)=>console.log(data.name))
```

Answer (score 1):

You had a , missing on second friends list

```js
const data = [
 {
    "index": "14",
    "name": "Bob",
    "age": "23",
    "friends": [
        {
          "id": 0,
          "name": "Lancaster Howell"
        }
     ],
  },
  {
    "index": "23",
    "name": "John",
    "age": "30",
     "friends": [
        {
          "id": 0,
          "name": "Lancaster Howell"
        },
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "TONY Howell"
        }
     ],
  },
];
 
data.forEach((objc) => {
   if (objc.friends.length > 1) {
   objc.friends.forEach((friends) => {
  var div=     document.getElementById('res');
  div.innerText +=friends.name+', ';
  
});}
});
```

```html
<div id="res"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

CHANGES based on fynsta comment, just logged the object name

```
data.forEach((object) => {
  if (object.friends.length > 1) {
    console.log(object.name)
  }
});
```